# Stopping echo username of user when he/she want choose some one to service PHP SQL

Tags: php

there is a dropdown list that fetch username from 'tablesite' tabel.

```
<?php
 ...
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT *
                       FROM  tablesite",$con2);
echo'* نام کاربری که به او خدمت داده اید: ','<br/>';           
echo '<select name="users" dir="rtl">';                
while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{ 
/* if there is username of curent user, do not echo that username and just echo other usernames. somthing like this: 
if(username='$username')
{...} */
echo '<option value="'.$amch['id_user'].'">'.$amch['username'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>'; 
?>
```

all things are true. but i need do not show username of current logged in user in this drop down list.

> here is how we can fetch current username's information:

```
$username=$fgmembersite->UserNameOfUser();
$user_id =$fgmembersite->UserID();
```

with using of these functions:

```
    function UserID()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['user_id'])?$_SESSION['user_id']:'';
}

function UserFullName()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely the easiest way is not to return the current username from the query?

```
$currentuserName = '';  //however you store the curent username
"SELECT * FROM tablesite WHERE username != '$currentuserName'";

or

$user_id = $fgmembersite->UserID();
"SELECT * FROM tablesite WHERE id_user != '$user_id'";
```

...which removes the neeed for any looped logic.

> You also need to stop using mysql_* functions, and look at either mysqli_* or PDO, as mysql_* functions are slowly being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{ 
/* if there is username of curent user, do not echo that username and just echo other usernames. somthing like this: 
if(username='$username')
{...} */
echo '<option value="'.$amch['id_user'].'">'.$amch['username'].'</option>';
}
```

with this:

```
$user_id =$fgmembersite->UserID();
while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{ 
  if ($user_id != $amch['id_user']) {
    echo '<option value="'.$amch['id_user'].'">'.$amch['username'].'</option>';
  }
}
```

That should be an approach...

Answer (score 1):

```
while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{ 
if ($amch['id_user'] != $_SESSION['user_id']) {
echo '<option value="'.$amch['id_user'].'">'.$amch['username'].'</option>';
}
}
```